# Devexpress UserControl, multiple windows

Tags: c#, devexpress

Using DevExpress components for aspx I created an `UserControl` that contains the `ASPxTreelist` control, and referenced this UC in a page.

I am facing problems when I open two instances of the same page, I get and error on `Refresh` or `Repaint` methods.

> Error Description: the object in used in other Thread

I tried to solve it using `InvokeRequired` but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code may help, since it uses the same data source, clone data may solve it.

```
private void UpdateGridDataSource(){
            DataTable clone = data.Copy();
            FillData(clone, deleting);
            deleting = !deleting;
            gridControl1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { gridControl1.DataSource = clone; }));
            data = clone;
        }
```

This looks similar to your issue https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E813/updating-a-grid-datasource-from-a-separate-thread